# Google bar chart remove bar when 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I want to be able to remove the spacing that is added when the value is 0 - in the example below there is a max of 4 answers so when the value is 0 removing the spacing will not stretch the graph so much.

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
 'packages': ['corechart']
});


// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {

 // Create the data table.
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'Course');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Excellent');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Adequate');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Limited');
 data.addColumn('number', 'None');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Very Confident');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Fairly Confident');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Somewhat Confident');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Not at all');
 data.addRows([

     ['Knowledge level', 1, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

     ['Assessment skills', 1, 9, 18, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0],

     ['Planning skills', 2, 7, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0],

     ['Confidence', 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
 ]);

 // Set chart options
 var options = {
     'title': 'Statewide Count across all courses',
     'width': 700,
     'height': 900
 };

 // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
 var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
 var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

 //Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
 /*google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
                                        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
                                        console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
                                    })*/
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Picture here

[image]

Comment: Setting `bar: {groupWidth: "100%"},` will decrease a bit the space, but there doesn´t seem to be a way to do what you want. The only solution I can think of is setting the option `isStacked: true` , but not sure if you want it to show that way

Comment: The chart reserves space for each bar on your axis, even when values are 0 or null, and there is no way to change this behavior.  You can mitigate it to an extent by stacking the bars (as @juvian pointed out), but this changes the display structure in a rather fundamental way.